Find files by extension and replacing characters before and after the search pattern
I need to find a files by extensions and replace the random characters before the search pattern to the specified text (REPLACED), turn the numbers after this pattern into an increasing counter and move 'em to another folder. Examples below:
find files by extension .EXT
/opt/files/QvmBIsB3_PATTERN_77580.EXT
/opt/files/8iV8QhFwQos_PATTERN_77580.EXT
/opt/files/lgI6JUEh55za488_PATTERN_77580.EXT

change 'em and replace to another folder:
/opt/replaced/REPLACED_PATTERN_1.EXT
/opt/replaced/REPLACED_PATTERN_2.EXT
/opt/replaced/REPLACED_PATTERN_3.EXT


OK, so what is the question? What do you have so far, and what is still giving you problems?

And what operating system are you using? We need to know so we know what tools and what versions/implementations of the various tools you have.

Linux 6.1.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.38-4 (2023-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have no clue how I can replace both part of a file around of the pattern. Could you help me with it?

For the time being, just forget the fact that they're filenames.  Treat it as text, and learn how to process the input text into the output text.  Once you have learned how to do that, then you can treat them as filenames.  But start with just a text-processing exercise.  That way you won't screw up your filenames if something goes wrong.

Is the increment based on any random order that the files can be output? Can it be based on length of filename and then locale sorting? Can it be based on birthtimes or modification times? Do you want the increment to be zero-padded?

With zsh, thanks to zmv:
autoload -zU zmv
n=1
zmv -n '/opt/files/*_(PATTERN)_*(.EXT)' '/opt/replaced/REPLACED_PATTERN_$((n++))$2'

Explanations:

The first argument to zmv is a shell pattern identifying files to rename.
The second argument is the replacement text.
You can use $1, $2, etc. in the replacement text to use the parts matched by parenthesized groups in the pattern.
$((n++)) increments $n after using its current value.
Remove -n to actually perform the task if you're happy.


Alternatively, you can use the Perl-based prename (rename package in Debian). Compared with zmv, it has the advantage of being installed by default on Debian, but the downside that it's more cryptic for many tasks including this one.
prename -n 'BEGIN {our $n = 1} our $n; s!.*_(PATTERN)_[0-9]+(\..*)$!/opt/replaced/REPLACED_PATTERN_$n$2! and ++$n' /opt/files/*_PATTERN_*.EXT

Explanations:

The first argument to prename is a Perl expression to execute on every file name. The old value of the implicit variable $_ is the current file name, and the file is renamed to the new value after evaluating the expression.
The BEGIN {…} block initializes $n before running the loop over file names. our $n declares $n as a global variable so that it can be used both in the BEGIN block and in the main expression.
s!…!…! performs a regular expression replacement.
The regex matches the desired pattern over the whole file (since it starts with .* and ends with $ — note that for simplicity, I assume that your file names don't contain newlines). Whatever matches PATTERN is saved in $1 and the extension is saved in $2 (the two parenthesized groups).
The replacement constructs a new file name in a different directory.
and ++$n increments the counter if the pattern matched.
Remove -n to actually perform the task if you're happy.


Thank you so much for your comment. I tried both methods but I've got an error in both cases. The first one case
./test.sh: line 5: zmv: command not found```

And in 2nd case I made test.pl, tried to start it I've got an error
```String found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 3, near "n 'BEGIN ..
        (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Not enough arguments for rename at ./test.pl line 3, near "n 'BEGIN ..

@anc For the first method, it's a zsh method, and you're trying it in bash. It won't work in bash. For the second method, I was missing a declaration, which is needed in modern perl, I've edited my answer.

I've tried your fixed perl mathod and I got an errors anyway
String found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 4, near  syntax error at ./test.pl line 4, near "n 'BEGIN  Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

@anc I'm not sure what you did, but it doesn't look right. The code I posted is a shell command, not something that goes into a .pl script.

Sorry, my bad. ( I tried run it as a .pl script, as a .sh script works like a charm! I wanna say again thank you so much!
